# What is local DataNode?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, bigdata

I am reading a hadoop module made by yahoo at https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module2.html and it is mentioned here "local DataNode" I would like to know what exactly is a local DataNode. My guess is a machine that is a NameNode and at the same time a DataNode but I want assurance of what it really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hadoop, by default, each block of data is copied 3 times (replication factor of 3).

To ensure the availability and durability of data, Hadoop places replicas in 3 different Data Nodes:

- Local Data Node: The Data Node where the client initiates a write (for e.g. using `hadoop fs -cp` command). The first replica is placed here. If the client is writing the data from outside the cluster, then this node is chosen at random. **It is the node on which the first replica gets written**.
- Off-rack Data Node: The Data Node, which is present on another rack. The second replica is placed here.
- On-Rack Data Node: The Data Node which is physically present on the same rack as the first Data Node. Third replica is placed here

This ensures that, even if one rack goes down, the data is still available on a Data Node present in another rack.

So in this tutorial, local Data Node means, the Data Node which initiated the write operation.

Let's take an example. Let's assume that you are trying to copy a file `a.txt` into HDFS. Let's assume that a cluster has 3 racks and is rack-aware:

```
Rack 1: Node 1, Node 2
Rack 2: Node 3, Node 4
Rack 3: Node 5, Node 6

Also, you have another Node: Node 7, which is outside the Hadoop cluster, but is connected 
to the cluster and you can perform HDFS operations.
```

**Case 1:** Client inside the cluster

Let's assume that you execute `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal a.txt /tmp/` from Node 1 (which is on Rack 1). Then Hadoop will try to place the replicas as follows:

- First replica is placed on Node 1. This is **Local Data Node** for the client
- Second replica is placed on either Rack 2 (Node 3 or Node 4) or Rack 3 (Node 5 or Node 6). This is **Off-Rack Data Node**.
- Third replica is placed on Node 2. This is **On-Rack Data Node**.

**Case 2:** Client outside the cluster

Let's assume that you execute `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal a.txt /tmp/` from Node 7 (which is not part of the cluster and the client runs on it). Then Hadoop will try to place the replicas as follows:

- It will randomly pick one of the nodes (any of the Nodes from Node 1 to Node 6). Then this node will become **Local Data Node**. Let's assume it picks Node 6, which is on Rack 3.
- Now, the second replica is placed either on Rack 1 (Node 1 or Node 2) or Rack 2 (Node 3 or Node 4). This is **Off-Rack Data Node**.
- Third replica is placed on Node 5. This is **On-Rack Data Node**

This is how ideally replica placement should happen. But, this depends on the space available on different racks and nodes.

Comment: So in Leghmann's term,, "local Data Node" is the first Data Node that made the process of mapping am I exactly right?

Comment: "first Data Node that made the process of mapping": I am not clear what do you mean by this? I will update the answer with an example

Comment: I am referring to MapReduce,, the first one that processes the mapper task is the local DataNode

Comment: No. Here we are not at all talking about jobs. This is about placement of data, when the data is getting written to HDFS. So, the data could get written as part of a MapReduce job or it could get ingested using tools like Flume. I have updated the answer with example.

Comment: You can say, Local Data Node is a node "on which the first replica gets written."

Comment: Manjunath : I want to confirm on once point on third replica. I have seen different articles quoting different options: Apache official documentation quote that : For the common case, when the replication factor is three, HDFS’s placement policy is to put one replica on one node in the local rack, another on a node in a different (remote) rack, and the last on a different node in the same remote rack. This implies one replica on current RAC & 2 replicas on remote RACs.

Comment: @Dean - Distributed Storage  framework HDFS ( Name node, Data node) and Distributed Processing framework YARN ( Resource Manager, Node manager and Application Master) are different. Currently we are talking about only Storage part. Mapreduce falls in distributed processing.

Comment: Great detailed explanation! HANDS DOWN to you!

Comment: For case 1 (client inside the cluster) I understand  that the reason for putting two blocks locally is simply the speed of data transfer -- local is faster. However, in case 2 (client outside the cluster), what is the reason for collocating the third block with one of the other two blocks? In other words, what's bad with putting the third block onto yet another rack?

Answer (score 1):

I too agree with Manjunath Ballur definition of **Local Data Node**

We can conclude that `Local Data Node` is the node where Client program writes first replica. You can treat Local Data Node is the DataNade in local RAC.

***Before addressing your query:***

Hadoop provides framework for ***`distributed storage`*** and ***`distributed processing`*** of large volumes of data in Tera/Peta bytes.

The article you have quoted is related to Distributed Storage  [HDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html)

***Regarding your query ***

> I am referring to MapReduce,, the first one that processes the mapper task is the local DataNode –

***The MapReduce framework consists of a single master ResourceManager, one slave NodeManager per cluster-node, and MRAppMaster per application*** ([see YARN Architecture Guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html)).

So block placement (HDFS write) does not have any relation to Map reduce processing.

The Mappers & Reducer nodes are selected on different criteria.

**Distributed Storage (HDFS):**

```
HDFS processes: Name Node / Stand By Name Node + Data Node
```

**Distributed Processing (Map Reduce/YARN):**

```
YARN processes : Resource Manager + Node Manager + Application Master (aka MRAppMaster)
```

Comment: Hands Down for the great explanation!